# Home networking issue

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, wireless-router, switch

I would like to put a wireless router in the main part of my house and a switch in the garage to avoid clutter and so I can have better wireless connectivity within the house for wireless devices.

My question is, if I have components connected to the router (media server, TV, game consoles...) and components connected to the switch (computers and other media servers) would the components on the switch be able to access the components on the router?

I have more than 4 hardwired rooms and I do not want to have all the cables coming into the cabinet where the Modem and Router are located but I would still want the ability to network all devices, those on the switch and those on the router.

Answer (score 1):

### If I have components connected to the router and components connected to the switch, would the components on the switch be able to access the components on the router?

---

Yes. Remember, your router will be a collection of devices and servers working together, and one of these devices is a switch. As long as all your devices are connected to each other with switches and are all within the same subnets, you should have no problems getting them to communicate with each other.

You should be sure you only have *one* DHCP server running on your network, which should be handled by your wireless router. Make sure your switch is connected to any of the LAN ethernet ports on your router and you should have no problems.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to **connect one port of your switch to your router's LAN port**, then all wireless (WLAN) devices connected to the router and all wired devices connected to the switch is on the same network and should be inter-accessible.